# How do i add extra value to a href

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to add extra values for links containing certain text.
I'm sure that's hella perverted code, but that's the best i could come up with. Doesn't work any way though...

```
$('a[href*="ambas"]').each(function() { 
   var linkattr1 = $(this).attr('href'); 
   $(this).attr('href',linkattr1 + "/?id=10261204")    
});
```

Comment: does the selector match?

Comment: Try `prop` instead of `attr`.

Comment: dont use jquery anyway use setAttribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

Comment: @ChaosClown not constructive.

Comment: @ChaosClown The whole point of using jQuery is to avoid having to get ugly like that.

Comment: This looks like the right idea. Does `$('a[href*="ambas"]')` actually show any elements if you run that on the console when on that page?

Comment: imho pure javascript is better then jQuery or other frameworks, but this is an endless discussion...

Comment: @Arazam Checked that `/` is not already at end of `href` before appending another `/` at `"/?id=10261204"`

Comment: i suggest omitting the slash anyway because its also allowed on files

Answer (score 0):

use

```
element.setAttribute('href',linkattr1 + "/?id=10261204");
```

and you should be able to keep everything else the same.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

Comment: did that. still no go   $('a[href*="ambas"]').each(function() { var linkattr1 = $(this).href('href'); element.setAttribute('href',linkattr1 + "/?id=10261204");)     });

Comment: does you selector match?

Comment: well, there is a link, that contains page called ambassadors (name is present in the href)

Comment: put an alert or console log within your each function to make sure it is firing. or check the error log.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("a[href*=ambas]").each(function(i, el) { 
    $(el).attr('href', function(_, link) {
        return link + "/?id=10261204"  
    })
});
```

```js
    $("a[href*=ambas]").each(function(i, el) { 
       $(el).attr('href', function(_, link) {
         return link + "/?id=10261204"  
       })
    }).each(function(i, el) {
      console.log($(el).attr("href"))
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="ambas">a</a>
<a href="ambas">a</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the javascript version without jQuery:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="ambas"]');

for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].setAttribute("href", links[i].getAttribute("href")+"?id=10261204");
}
```